# get id of textarea using type selector didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

http://jsfiddle.net/bBgbR/1/

```
var catId = $("input[type='text']:visible").attr('id');
```

is my selector correct? I want to get the visible textarea's id.

```
<textarea type="text" id="text_lp1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like

```
var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
catId = catId.replace('text_lp', '');
alert(catId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```

Please note that the element that you are targeting is `textarea` but you had written a selector that will select an `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```

because you've used `textarea` not `input`, you also need to remove `type="text"` from your `textarea` element

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBgbR/8/)**

If you want to use it as an `input` element then your HTML should look like:

```
<input type="text" id="text_lp1" />
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBgbR/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
var cartIdAttribute = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```

The problem, you search **INPUT** element, but you need **TEXTAREA** element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
  var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBgbR/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `input[type='text']` which wrong. use like:

```
var catId = $("textarea:visible").attr('id');
```